# How to Update in existing quantity in amazon seller using amazon marketplace web service

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to Update in existing quantity in amazon seller using amazon marketplace web service.when update product then old quantity remove and new quantity add.but I want existing quantity Update. For ex. old Quantity 5 then update 10 more Quantity then total quantity 5+10 = 15.

1. My Code.

   require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

   if ($client->validateCredentials()) {

   ```
               $product = new MCS\MWSProduct();

               $product->sku             = $request['ItemSKU'];
               $product->price           = $request['SalePrice'];
               $product->quantity        = $request['Qty'];
               $product->product_id      = $request['ASINNo'];;
               $product->product_id_type = $request['ProductType'];;
               $product->condition_type  = $request['ConditionType'];;
               $product->title           = $request['Title'];;
               $product->sale_price      = $request['SalePrice'];
   ```

   //print_r($product);
                   if ($product->validate()) {

   ```
                   $result = $client->postProduct($product);  

                   if($result){

                      $arr['status']   = TRUE; 
                      $arr['submitid'] = $result['FeedSubmissionId'];
                      $info = $client->GetFeedSubmissionResult($result['FeedSubmissionId']);                      
                   }                      

               }
   ```

2 . One another code :

```
$client = new MCS\MWSClient([
                'Marketplace_Id'      => $Amazon_MarketPlaceId,
                'Seller_Id'           => $Amazon_SellerId,
                'Access_Key_ID'       => $Amazon_AWSAccessKeyId,
                'Secret_Access_Key'   => $Amazon_SecretKey,
                'MWSAuthToken'        => $Amazon_MWSAuthToken
            ]);
            if ($client->validateCredentials()) {  
                foreach($request as $key => $value){

                $SKU_Prices[$key]   = $value;
                }

                if(!empty($SKU_Prices)){    
            $result = $client->updatePrice($SKU_Prices);

    if($result){

    $arr['status']      = TRUE; 
    $arr['submitid']    = $result['FeedSubmissionId'];
    }else{

    $arr['status']      = FALSE;
    $arr['submitid']    = 0;    
    }
      }
     }
```

Please let me know how to Update.